npx tailwind css init not working in powershell
when I run npx tailwindcss init in my poweshell it shows this. I don't know what this means.
npm error code ENOENT

npm error syscall lstat

npm error path C:\\Users\\cv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm

npm error errno -4058

npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\\Users\\cv\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'

npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm error enoent

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\cv\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\2024-08-24T08_27_09_429Z-debug-0.log

I don't know what to do it, because I cannot understand this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
